# Running R code from selected multiple (but not all) code chunks in Rstudio

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio

I want to use R code interactively within R studio (and therefore rely on the global environment) when developing the script (and so without knitting the document) - going to each chunk individually and pressing run chunk is tedious and error-prone (I often miss chunks) - is there another way to run parts of a .Rmd file and have the variables available in the global environment?

n.b., I have just placed a feature request to RStudio to be able to run chunks in selected code - however I would be surprised that a recommended methodology for developing/testing R code across multiple chunks (without knitting) is not already supported.

Comment: Rstudio has a menu "run all" that runs all chunks. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: No - I only want to run the first part of the script.  There is the option to start with the first chunk and then iteratively select Run Next Chunk (Ctl-Alt-N) but again this is tedious with many chunks

Comment: @user1420372 did you come across a solution to this?

Comment: This was asked in 2014 .. I think "Run all chunks above" and "Run all chunks below" was added after this question was asked and is a good way there.

Comment: It's a shame there is still no solution to this